# Radius SQL query - optimize

Tags: mysql, sql, freeradius, radius

I am no SQL guru at all, but I have an SQL query that has been used automated on a small FreeRadius server. Now we want to use it on a bigger server, but i noticed the query takes a long time, and utilizes CPU 100% for about two minutes...

Does anyone have an idea on how to optimize the query? The goal is to find if a user has more than one active login, and get info on the oldest.

We can also accept more results, and do the sorting in PHP, to reduce the load on the radius-database.

Here is the query we use today:

```
  SELECT username, acctstarttime, acctsessionid, nasipaddress, framedipaddress
        FROM radacct
        WHERE username IN (
            SELECT username
            FROM radacct
            WHERE acctstoptime IS NULL
            GROUP BY username
            HAVING COUNT(username) > 1
        )
        AND acctstoptime IS NULL
        GROUP BY username
        ORDER BY username, acctstarttime ASC
```

Regards

Kim

Comment: Kindly include the execution plan. You can use `EXPLAIN` to get this.

Comment: Also indicate the schema of the table, volume of data, specs of the server, etc.... They may not be needed in this particular case to let you get an improvement, but you should always include them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can just make a single pass over the entire `radacct` table:

```
SELECT username, MIN(acctstarttime) AS min_start_time
FROM radacct
WHERE acctstoptime IS NULL
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

This would return only users having two or more active accounts.  And it would also return the latest `acctstarttime` value for each user.

Comment: I think this is working, with a slight modification:

    SELECT username, MIN( acctstarttime ) AS min_start_time
FROM radacct
WHERE acctstoptime IS NULL 
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT( * ) >=2
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: I am trying to understand the original query, and inside my head, the outer query is obsolete, as all data we need is inside one table? Looks like the outer would make more sense if it was getting other info from different tables. Am i onto something here?

Comment: Each user may have multiple records.  The query I wrote is an aggregate over the same multiple username.  So we can't report individual non aggregate fields, because we don't know which one to report.  If, for example, you wanted the fields from the user with the smallest account start time, then we could join the query I have above back to `radacct`.

Answer (score 0):

Either you remove subquery

```
SELECT username, acctstarttime, acctsessionid, nasipaddress, framedipaddress
        FROM radacct
        WHERE acctstoptime IS NULL
        GROUP BY username
        ORDER BY username, acctstarttime ASC
        HAVING COUNT(username) > 1
```

or remove `group by` from outer query (if you expect to get all the rows with duplicate `username`

Comment: The query has problems besides this.

Answer (score 0):

The query responses are 100% correct you should be able to do this with a single pass. However 2 minutes is insane! I also suspect with a single pass this is not as quick as you want. 
We have a status page to display all users who are online at any given moment for support reasons sounds like this is similar to what you are trying to do.

First make sure you have an index on acctstoptime.
I also suspect you have some bad configuration in MYSQL configuration to deal with this large of a table. 
I would also highly recommend doing an archive database and keeping all active sessions in a small database that will help a lot with high volume of update and inserts that free radius accounting does.

We have well over 100,000 daily active users with a interim update of 300seconds and generate about 3-4billion rows a year. every query we have is well under 1 second. I would be happy to help you optimize your free radius stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but i got it sorted out. The original query was flawed, it did iterate all radacct entrys, once per entry...so, it was more of a loop than anything else.

We allow users to login twice on the hotspot, but afterwards we find and kick the oldest login. We do this so the user can change his router or login at another location without logging off manually first, but he still can only use one login at a time. Also, sessions do not time out, they are meant to be permanent as long as the user has a valid subscription.

Mikrotiks Hotspot does not do this  itself, so it needs some help.